# Does a continuous bijection from a compact, hausdorff space imply it is an homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a bijective, continuous map between two toplogical spaces. Does X being compact and Hausdorff imply that $f$ must be a homeomorphism? I think it doesn't but I can not find an example.

Comment: Others have answered the question really well but many a times, a thing to notice is the definition of homeomorphism which is defined to be $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous (some authors require $f$ to be bijective as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be your favourite compact Hausdorff space with at least $2$ points, let $Y$ be $X$ with the trivial topology, consider the identity as $f$.

Comment: I think you should specify what you mean by trivial: is it the discrete topology or the anti-discrete topology? This clearly cannot be true for the discrete topology since $f$ itself need not be continuous.

Comment: @PankajTiwari [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) is the common name for the topology with only two open sets even though some authors use indiscrete or other names

Comment: I thought the OP might not be familiar with the terminology so might end up getting confused. Anyways you're answer is of course correct so +1!

Comment: Also many people use the Hausdorff condition as an axiom for a topological space so one has to double check what defintions they're using.

Comment: @GeneralGrievous I've never seen anyone assuming that topological spaces are Hausdorff, without explicitly stating this somewhere. And definitely I've never seen anyone including Hausdorff axiom in the definition of topological space.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ has the property that every compact subset $A\subseteq Y$ is closed, then $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous, so $f$ is a homeomorphism. For instance, compact sets are closed in a Hausdorff space.

Since $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}$ is continuous iff $f$ is an open map iff $f$ is a closed map. Let $B\subseteq X$ be closed. Since $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $B$ is compact. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(K)$ is also compact, thus closed. Consequently, $f$ is a closed map.